Average of decision variable in MIP
I have a MIP model that minimizes the cost of workforce scheduling. The objective function and other constraints do not play a major role, only the following constraint is relevant:
$$\delta_i =\mid \sum_t y_{it} - \bar{y}\mid $$
Of course, this is linearized in the model.$\delta_i$ is a deviation parameter for the objective function, $y_{it}$ is binary and indicates whether employee $i$ is working on day $t$. $\bar{y}$ is the average of all daily assignments across all employees. Is this formulation with the mean value in the form of $\bar{y}$ a valid formulation for a MIP or not?

If you mean that $\overline y = \frac{1}{I\cdot T}\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{t=1}^T y_{it},$ then use of $\overline y$  will not create any problems with the formulation.
